# Boost Serialization - Serialize std::tr1::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, tr1, boost-serialization

Boost::Serialization has builtin support for `boost::shared_ptr<>`.

Is there a way to use this support for `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` too?
Is it possible to cast from `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` to `boost::shared_ptr<>`?

Comment: If you can use boost anyway, why don't you just use `boost::shared_ptr` in the first place ?

Comment: Cause the interface is boost-independent. Using boost::serialization for serializing the classes is just an implementation-detail. If later another developer decides to use another implementation for serialization, the project would still be boost-dependant.

Comment: Why don't just use `typedef boost::shared_ptr MySharedPtr`, so your code factically would be not boost-dependent, but typedef-dependent. You could change both serialization library and typedefs in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A casting will not be possible as implementations differ. Also creating an instance of the one shared_ptr type with the value returned from get() on the other shared_ptr type will not work correctly as the reference countings will go to 0 at different points in your code which leads to deletion of the object before the last use of it.
I am not an expert of boost::serialization but as the interfaces of std::tr1::shared_ptr<> and boost::shared_ptr<> are nearly identical it is very likely that you can just clone the serialization/deserialization code of boost::shared_ptr<> and only have to replace the namespace of the shared_ptr.