# c++0x std::shared_ptr vs. boost::shared_ptr

Tags: python, c++11, boost, shared-ptr, python-c-api

I have a c++ code which heavily uses `shared_ptr` and STL. A common header says

```
#include<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using boost::shared_ptr;  // for shared_ptr
using namespace std;      // for STL
```

I wanted to switch to c++0x now to make use of the language features, using gcc 4.6 with `-std=c++0x`. There is however `std::shared_ptr` now as well, leading to ambiguity for unspecified `shared_ptr` (`boost::shared_ptr` vs `std::shared_ptr`).

When switching to `std::shared_ptr` instead, like this:

```
#include<memory>
using namespace std;      // for STL; also imports std::shared_ptr
```

then I am getting problems with `boost::python`, which works apprently with `boost::shared_ptr` only (at least without further fiddling):

```
/usr/include/boost/python/object/make_ptr_instance.hpp:30:52: error: no matching function for call to 'get_pointer(const std::shared_ptr<Cell>&)'
```

My question therefore is

- if there is a simple solution to resolve the ambiguity between `boost::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (other than not using c++0x for now), and also
- if `boost::shared_ptr` will eventually be just an alias for `std::shared_ptr`; that would solve my problem automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: THE solution would probably be to get rid of `using namespace std` all together. And it could be as simple as doing a global find&replace for every stl element.

Comment: Right, that would be THE solution, but STL is used so frequently that it would make the code much less readable; perhaps I could consider writing bunch of `using std::string; using std::vector; ` etc declarations in the common header. It is actually not many `std::` parts which are used, but they are used very often.

Comment: @eudoxos: it takes some getting used to, but the amenability of the code increases so much; Also, I find my self just adding `using std::cout; using std::string`  inside the scope that uses it. That increases readability, especially in less trivial cases (`using boost::phoenix::bind` or `using boost:bind`, or `using boost::spirit::karma::_1` etc. Removes any ambiguity (to both compiler and programmers) without cluttering up the actual code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to the define the freestanding function 'get_pointer' for your shared pointer class for it to work with Boost Python. *(Note that this enables you to write your own shared pointer, and still work with Boost Python: this is a conscious design effort to prevent tight coupling of distinct Boost libraries)*.

You might get that using the boost tr1 compatibility headers, but I haven't tried.

http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/tr1.pdf

> When Boost.TR1 is configured to make use of your standard library's native TR1 implementation, then it doesn't do very much: it
>   just includes the appropriate header.
>
> When Boost.TR1 is using the Boost implementation of a particular component, then it includes the appropriate Boost header(s) and
>   imports the necessary declarations in namespace std::tr1 with using declarations. Note that only those declarations that are part
>   of the standard are imported: the implementation is deliberately quite strict about not including any Boost-specific extensions in
>   namespace std::tr1, in order to catch any portability errors in user code. If you really need to use Boost-specific extensions then
>   you should include the Boost headers directly and use the declarations in namespace boost:: instead. Note that this style of implementation
>   is not completely standards-conforming, in particular it is not possible to add user-defined template specializations of
>   TR1 components into namespace std::tr1. There are also one or two Boost libraries that are not yet fully standards conforming,
>   any such non-conformities are documented in the TR1 by subject section. Hopefully, occurrences of non-standard behavior should
>   be extremely rare in practice however.
>
> If you use the standard conforming header includes (in boost/tr1/tr1) then these header names can sometimes conflict with existing
>   standard library headers (for example shared_ptr is added to the existing standard library header  rather than it's
>   own header). These headers forward on to your existing standard library header in one of two ways: for gcc it uses #include_next,
>   and for other compilers it uses the macro BOOST_TR1_STD_HEADER(header) (defined in boost/tr1/detail/config.hpp) which evaluates
>   to #include <../include/header>. This should work "straight out the box" for most compilers, but does mean that these
>   headers should never be placed inside a directory called "include" that is already in your compiler's search path.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be more complicated with boost::python. Well, now I use boost::serialization as well, and it does not seem to be as flexible (e.g. [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094604/boost-serialization-serialize-stdtr1shared-ptr) suggests to copy & customize what boost::serialization does for boost::shared_ptr.