# Boost.Python and Polymorphic Behaviour with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr, boost-python

I would like to know how classes `A` and `B` below can work polymorphically in python when using `std::shared_ptr` instead of `boost::shared_ptr`?

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : A
{
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

void f(const std::shared_ptr<A>& ptr)
{}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    class_<A, boost::noncopyable>("A", no_init);

    class_<B, std::shared_ptr<B>, bases<A>>("B")
        .def(init<>());

    def("f", f);
}
```

I am aware that the the `boost::get_pointer` method must be defined for `std::shared_ptr`, so I make sure that the following lines exist before a `#include <boost/python.hpp>`:

```
namespace boost {
template<class T> const T* get_pointer(const std::shared_ptr<T>& p)
{
    return p.get();
}

template<class T> T* get_pointer(std::shared_ptr<T>& p)
{
    return p.get();
}
} // namespace boost
```

Now, in python I try:

```
>>> from test import *
>>> b = B()
>>> f(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    test.f(B)
did not match C++ signature:
    f(std::shared_ptr<A>)
```

Note: The code above works fine for `boost::shared_ptr`, but I want to stick with the C++11 types instead.

Thanks.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles upon this, @eudoxos has a working solution that below. You don't need to switch to `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Python has special magic built in to recognize a boost::shared_ptr. It does not currently recognize a std::shared_ptr. For now, just frown and use boost::shared_ptr.

Comment: Boost.python can use std::shared_ptr via get_pointer, what you write is not true.

Comment: std::shared_ptr is only recently supported. In boost 1.47 it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I made once `std::shared_ptr` work with boost::python IIRC, using `get_pointer` as you write. (The relevant comment is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6569028/761090)). My guess is that you need to have `class_<A,std::shared_ptr<A>,...>` since that is what your function takes as argument.

Comment: I tried `class_<A, std::shared_ptr<A>>("A")`, but no luck. It compiles fine, but it fails in python.

Comment: Did you actually post a **real** code?? I am unable to compile that at all without some modifications. Could you, please?

Comment: I posted on the c++-sig forum [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.c++/15759), because it looks like a bug or at least unexpected behavior. Let's see what the boost:;python guys say.

Comment: There is an answer at c++-sig [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.c++/15759/focus=15771). To summarize, you have to say `implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<B2>,std::shared_ptr<A2>>();
`.